How to prevent loss of current in WS2811 addressable LEDs
I am currently trying to control 300 WS2811 LEDs with an ESP8266.  The software side of the project is fine.  However, the LEDs towards the end of the strip are not receiving enough power (turning red as it gets closer to the end).  I am using this 5V-60A power supply.  My calculations (from the description on Amazon) say that I need 0.3W per LED (I am unsure if that means per LED in the package or for the entire 3 LED light so I am going with the former) x 3 LEDs per light x 300 = 270W.  The ESP8266 should only be drawing about 1W so I am still above the required power level with this supply.
The My wiring is as follows:

positive on power supply to VIN on ESP8266 and red wire on the WS2811 harness.
negative on power supply to GND on ESP8266 and blue wire on the WS2811 harness.
Pin D4 on the ESP8266 to white wire on the WS2811 harness.

I am thinking that I need to supply more current through the two extra red and blue lines on each strip.  My initial attempt was to leave it wired as is but add a positive and negative line coming from the extra terminals on the power supply and connect them to the extra red a blue wires.  I then connected all of the strands together with those wires and double checked for continuity through the entire strand.  Still no change in brightness though.
Are my assumptions incorrect?  Is there something else I need to connect?

5v strips are best for short segments. 12v strips are a better choice for long strips. The Ws2815 draws just 12.5 mA per pixel, meaning about 4x lower voltage drop than what you're using. 24v are better still, but usually are not individually addressable.

Your LED strip is almost certainly not rated to run 22.5A through any section of its traces; you are seeing voltage drop over the resistance.
You need to read the datasheet to see what the maximum allowable length is and make sure that you have hardwired connections back to the power supply (which themselves must be sized for the current) to supply power at close enough intervals such that no part of the strip is more than the maximum length away from a power connection. Fuses would also be a good idea.
